# Adding options to select element at the point it's about to open in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a system with a fast-changing set of items that may appear as options in select boxes. I could update the options themselves directly each time the data changes, but I'd rather simply fill in the options at the point where the user is about to see them. E.g. when it's about to open. Is there an event for this?

I suppose I could use the 'click' or 'mousedown' event, but what about navigating via the keyboard? There may be other cases too (perhaps)

BTW, I know *how* to add options to a select, the 'opening' event is really what I'm after.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`focus()`** and not `click()` because the click event does not give enough time to populate the drop down with new values which causes quirky behavior. Also the click event will  only capture mouse clicks, with the focus() you get both mouse and keyboard focus events and also it gives ample time for the drop down to get populated with new data. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMTRk/2/) with some simple experiments, try each function one at a time to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to work, though it resets the selection each time you click on the select. I suppose this is easily fixed by ensuring that the select attribute is correctly set when filling in the html().

Comment: I've used this suggestion in my app now and it seems to work well, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've got two choices: `click()` and `focus()` there are no others.

Comment: No, they won't open it, but they're valid ways of capturing an event to populate the contents BEFORE it opens, which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something like this, a select drop down probably isnt going to be the UI element of choice.

I would recommend changing to a jQuery UI Autocomplete widget; then you can simply serve items based on the query the user entered.

In addition, you can attach to the keyup event (or the focus event), and show a set of items at that point (as if the 'drop down' was clicked on) http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#maxheight

Comment: AutoComplete is a nice control, but I really want a drop-down with no typing required. Thanks though!